# MariaDB: ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

When i try to execute a query i got error:

```
  MariaDB [suitecrm]> select *   from waiter_log;
    ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
    No connection. Trying to reconnect...
```

An error does not occur every time:

```
MariaDB [suitecrm]> select count(*) from waiter_log;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    64418348
Current database: suitecrm

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      893 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.13 sec)

MariaDB [suitecrm]> select count(*) from waiter_log; 
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      893 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***/etc/my.cnf***

```
max_allowed_packet = 128M
interactive_timeout=20
wait_timeout=20
```

Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Check the MariaDB log - e.g. in `/var/lib/mariadb/mariadb.log` or whatever is suitable for your distribution.

Comment: Nothing about it

Comment: do you have a pause between executing different queries? if the pause longer 20s then you will have the error "mysql server gone away". It does not mean that mysql gone, in your case in means that connection was killed.

Comment: ravnur, You're right. When pause more than 20 sec i get error